# Import error with Python Django

Tags: python, django

(Note: I have found a workaround, as stated at the bottom, but it seems like the wrong way to go about this.)

`views.py` and `forms.py` are both in

`R:\\jeffy\\programming\\sandbox\\python\\django_files\\tutorial\\django_test\\django_test\\`

and

`R:\\jeffy\\programming\\sandbox\\python\\django_files\\tutorial\\django_test\\`

is in Django's "Python Path"

But when attempting

```
from forms import MyRegistrationForm
```

in `views.py`, it results in an `ImportError ... No module named 'forms'`.

<s>I changed it to</s>

```
from django_test.forms import MyRegistrationForm
```

but that results in `SyntaxError ... invalid syntax`.

Since

`R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\python\django_files\tutorial\django_test\django_test`

is a package (it has the empty `__init__.py` file in it), I thought I could refer to `django_test` in this way. (It's also the Django project name.)

I can manually add

`R:\\jeffy\\programming\\sandbox\\python\\django_files\\tutorial\\django_test\\django_test\\`

to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (Windows 7, 32 bit, Django 1.7c2), and get it to work. But since this implies that *every* Django project must be added to the `PYTHONPATH`, it seems like it should be able to work without having to do this.

Am I correct? Is there a way to import `forms.py` from `views.py` (which is in the same directory) without having to manually add its directory to the `PYTHONPATH`?

Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate on `SyntaxError ... invalid syntax` ? May be that is what you need to address. Also, for the first case, do `from .forms import MyRegistrationForm `

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the syntax error. I eliminated the `django_test\django_test` element from `PYTHONPATH` and now `from django_test.forms import MyRegistrationForm` works. So I don't know what I did while I was fooling around with this. But your idea also works: `from .forms import MyRegistrationForm`. Is that similar to the Windows `./sub-directory` notation?

Comment: @karthikr You should write it up in an answer so I can give you credit. Thank you.

Comment: no.. while importing, `.forms` looks for a module named `forms` in the current package.

Comment: That is fine, you may accept the answer of the answerer if you choose to :) @aliteralmind

Comment: @karthikr That is generous of you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in the same directory, try a relative import:

```
from .forms import MyRegistrationForm
```

*EDIT:* Someone posted this same suggestion as a comment already. I didn't see the comment.